# Plotting proportional data python (stacked barplot)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a data set where clients answer a question, and clients belong to a certain category. The category is ordinal. I want to visualize the change in percentages as a proportional stacked barplot. Here is some test data:

```
answer | categ
1        1
2        1
3        2
1        2
2        3
3        3
1        1
2        1
3        2
1        2
2        3
3        3
1        3
2        2
3        1
```

Here is how you can generate it:

```
pd.DataFrame({'answer':[1,2,3]*5, 'categ':[1,1,2,2,3,3]*2+[3,2,1]})
```

Using some convoluted code which can probably be written much nicer and more efficient I got to percentages within the answer.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'answer':[1,2,3]*5, 'categ':[1,1,2,2,3,3]*2+[3,2,1]})
rel_data = pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(test.groupby(['answer','categ']).size()).reset_index(),pd.DataFrame(test.groupby('answer').size()).reset_index(), how='left', on='answer')
rel_data.columns = ['answer', 'categ', 'number_combination', 'number_answer']
rel_data['perc'] = rel_data['number_combination']/rel_data['number_answer']
rel_data[['answer', 'categ', 'perc']]
```

This results in:

```
answer | categ | perc
1        1       0.4
1        2       0.4
1        3       0.2
2        1       0.4
2        2       0.2
2        3       0.4
3        1       0.2
3        2       0.4
3        3       0.4
```

How do I get this into a stacked bar plot with per answer a bar and colored areas per category?

Answer (score 2):

Once I had the last dataframe, I could get it fairly easily. By doing this:

```
rel_data = rel_data.groupby(['answer','categ']).\
    perc.sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ylim=(0,1))
```

It's again dirty but at least it got the job done. The perc.sum turns it into one value per group (even though it already was that), the unstack() turns it into a DF with the categories as columns and the answers as rows, the plot turns this into a proportional stacked barplot. The ylim is due to some tiny rounding error where it could add up to 1.00001 which added a whole new tick.

Comment: Dude that is a badass one liner!

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means perfect but it's a start:

```
for i in set(df.categ):
    colors = ["r", "g", "b", "y", "o"] #etc....
    if i == 1:
        x = np.zeros(len(set(df.answer)))
    else:
        x += df[df.categ == i - 1].perc.as_matrix()

    plt.bar(df[df.categ == i].answer, df[df.categ == i].perc, bottom=x, color=colors[i - 1])

plt.xticks(list(set(df.answer)))
plt.show()
```

The approach is to group the data first by category and then we can iterate over each category to get the answers which will be the individual bars. We then check if its the first iteration by the `i == 1` check. This creates an empty array which will be used when stacking. Then we draw the first bars. Then we iterate and add the height of the bars as we go into the variable x.

The colors array are there just so you can differentiate the bars a bit better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a barplot with the matplotlib library. Follow this tuto : http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html